# Как вывести информацию из txt файла?

Tags: php

Есть файл с разными запросами
Например: `keywords.txt`
В файле в каждой новой строке лежит ключевик Пример:

```
кино
сериал
смотреть кино
погода сегодня хорошая
```

Как сделать вывод ключевиков из файла таким образом:

```
<a href="mydomen.com/search.php?jjj=kino" title="кино">кино</a>
<a href="mydomen.com/search.php?jjj=serial" title="сериал">сериал</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну как-то так:

```
<?php
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('keywords.txt'));
while (list($key, $value) = each($array)) {
echo "<a href=\"mydomen.com/search.php?jjj=" . $value . "\" title=\"" . $value. "\">" . $value . "</a><br>\n";
}
?>
```

Замену пробелов в строках, содержащих более одного ключевого слова, на значение %20 осильте сами. Если нет - подскажем.

-- Дополняю ответ с примером транслитерации --

```
<?php

function rus2translit($string) {

    $converter = array(

        'а' => 'a',   'б' => 'b',   'в' => 'v',

        'г' => 'g',   'д' => 'd',   'е' => 'e',

        'ё' => 'e',   'ж' => 'zh',  'з' => 'z',

        'и' => 'i',   'й' => 'y',   'к' => 'k',

        'л' => 'l',   'м' => 'm',   'н' => 'n',

        'о' => 'o',   'п' => 'p',   'р' => 'r',

        'с' => 's',   'т' => 't',   'у' => 'u',

        'ф' => 'f',   'х' => 'h',   'ц' => 'c',

        'ч' => 'ch',  'ш' => 'sh',  'щ' => 'sch',

        'ь' => '\'',  'ы' => 'y',   'ъ' => '\'',

        'э' => 'e',   'ю' => 'yu',  'я' => 'ya',

        'А' => 'A',   'Б' => 'B',   'В' => 'V',

        'Г' => 'G',   'Д' => 'D',   'Е' => 'E',

        'Ё' => 'E',   'Ж' => 'Zh',  'З' => 'Z',

        'И' => 'I',   'Й' => 'Y',   'К' => 'K',

        'Л' => 'L',   'М' => 'M',   'Н' => 'N',

        'О' => 'O',   'П' => 'P',   'Р' => 'R',

        'С' => 'S',   'Т' => 'T',   'У' => 'U',

        'Ф' => 'F',   'Х' => 'H',   'Ц' => 'C',

        'Ч' => 'Ch',  'Ш' => 'Sh',  'Щ' => 'Sch',

        'Ь' => '\'',  'Ы' => 'Y',   'Ъ' => '\'',

        'Э' => 'E',   'Ю' => 'Yu',  'Я' => 'Ya',

    );

    return strtr($string, $converter);

}

$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('file.txt'));
while (list($key, $value) = each($array)) {
    echo "<a href=\"mydomen.com/search.php?jjj=" . rus2translit($value) . "\" title=\"" . $value. "\">" . $value . "</a><br>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: выводит так
<a href="mydomen.com/search.php?jjj="кино" title="кино">кино</a><br>
а надо так:
<a href="mydomen.com/search.php?jjj=kino" title="кино">кино</a><br>

Comment: То есть в url должны русские слова делать замену на english (translit)

Comment: Скопируйте еще раз. Вообще удивительно, как нельзя на готовом примере позиционно догадаться, где убрать лишнюю кавычку.

Comment: Да с кавычкой я разобрался , меня больше транслит интересует

Comment: Ну с этого и надо было начинать, а то о транслите в вопросе не указано. Как сделать? Копируем функцию отсюда http://htmlweb.ru/php/example/translit.php (или любую аналогичную), а затем вместо куска jjj=" . $value пишем jjj=" . rus2translit($value)

Comment: См. дополненный ответю